# Execute Backup-SqlDatabase cmdlet remotely

Tags: backup, powershell, sql-server-2012, teamcity

When I run the following script line locally on an SQL Server machine, it executes perfectly:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $sqldbname -BackupFile "$($backupFolder)$($dbname)_db_$($addinionToName).bak"
```

$serverName contains a short name of the SQL Server instance. SQL Server is 2012, so these new cmdlets work like a charm.

On the other hand, when I am trying to perform a DB backup from a TeamCity agent machine like this (Through Invoke-Command cmdlet):

```
function BackupDB([String] $serverName, [String] $sqldbname, [String] $backupFolder, [String] $addinionToName)
{
    Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking

    Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $sqldbname -BackupFile "$($backupFolder)$($dbname)_db_$($addinionToName).bak"
}

Invoke-Command -computername $SQLComputerName -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock ${function:BackupDB} -ArgumentList $SQLInstanceName, $DatabaseName, $BackupDirectory, $BakId
```

results in an error:

> Failed to connect to server $serverName.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], ConnectionFailureException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.M
>   anagement.PowerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand

What is the correct way to execute Backup-SqlDatabase cmdlet remotely?

Answer (score 1):

You can just install three modules from SQL Feature pack that provides the SQLPS functionality and use it without Invoke. Get and install in this order:

> Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Microsoft®
>   SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects  Microsoft® Windows
>   PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012

from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065). After this you can run them localy and access remote SQL servers back to SQL 2000. Read [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/backup-and-restore-sql-server-with-the-sql-server-2012-powershell-cmdlets/) for some help.